Expected Entropy of the Empirical Distribution
Given a distribution on $n$ outcomes where outcome $i$ has probability $p_i$, the Shannon entropy of the distribution is defined as $- \sum_{i = 1}^n p_i \cdot \log_2 p_i$.
Let's suppose I sample from the above distribution 100 times to create an empirical distribution over the outcomes. So for example, if I see outcome number five 60 times in my sample of 100, then I will say that the empirical probability of outcome five is $\hat p_5 = 0.6$.
I can now ask about the Shannon entropy of this empirical distribution $\hat p$. The Shannon entropy of $\hat p$ may be lower than that of $p$, and it also could be higher depending on my sample.
So my question is: What is the expected value of the Shannon entropy of the empirical distribution, as a function of the number of samples $n$? If this is hard to answer in general, is it known for simple distributions like the uniform distribution on just 2 outcomes?

Updated my answer after I found a reduction in the expression. The time complexity of the algo is now $\mathcal{O}(nm)$ from $\mathcal {O} ({n + m -1 \choose n-1} n)$

Edit: Added some major optimizations
Not a closed form equation for the expected entropy, but an algorithm to compute it.
Here $n$ is the number of outcomes with probabilities $[p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n]$, and $m$ is the number of samples taken. Then
$$ \begin{split}
E(S_m) &= \sum_{x\in\mathcal{D}(S_m)} \left(x\cdot P(S_m = x) \right)\\
&= \sum_{a_i \ge 0, \sum a_i = m} \left(
\left( - \sum_{i=1, a_i \not = 0}^{i=n} \left( \frac{a_i}{m} \log_2 \frac{a_i}{m} \right) \right)
\left( \frac{m!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} (a_i!)} \prod_{i=1}^{n} {p_i}^{a_i} \right)
\right) \\
&= \sum_{a_i \ge 0, \sum a_i = m} \left(
\left(\log_2 m - \frac{\sum_{i=1, a_i \not = 0}^{i=n} \left( a_i \log_2 a_i \right)}{m} \right)
\left( \frac{m!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} (a_i!)} \prod_{i=1}^{n} {p_i}^{a_i} \right)
\right) \\
&= \log_2 m - \sum_{a_i \ge 0, \sum a_i = m} \left( \sum_{j=1, a_j \not = 0}^{j=n} \left( a_j \log_2 a_j \left( \frac{(m-1)!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} (a_i!)} \prod_{i=1}^{n} {p_i}^{a_i} \right) \right)  \right) \\
&= \log_2 m - \sum_{j=1}^{j=n} \left( \sum_{a_i \ge 0, \sum a_i = m, a_j > 0} \left( a_j \log_2 a_j \left( \frac{(m-1)!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} (a_i!)} \prod_{i=1}^{n} {p_i}^{a_i} \right) \right) \right) \\
&= \log_2 m - \sum_{j=1}^{j=n} \left( \sum_{a_j=1}^{m} \left( (a_j \log_2 a_j) \sum_{a_i \ge 0, \sum a_i = m} \left( \frac{(m-1)!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n} (a_i!)} \prod_{i=1}^{n} {p_i}^{a_i} \right) \right) \right) \\
&= \log_2 m - \sum_{j=1}^{j=n} \left( \sum_{a_j=1}^{m} \left( (a_j \log_2 a_j) \left( \frac{(m-1)! \: p_j^{a_j} (1-p_j)^{m-a_j}}{a_j! (m-a_j)!} \right) \right) \right) \\
&= \log_2 m - (m-1)! \sum_{i=2}^{m} \left( \frac{\log_2 i}{(i-1)! (m-i)!} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \left( p_j^i (1-p_j)^{m-i} \right) \right) \\
\end{split}$$
This can be calculated in $\mathcal{O} \left( mn \right)$ time. Another way to write this is as

$\log_2 m$ subtracted by sum of ($\frac{i log_2 i}{m}$ multiplied by the coefficient of $x^i$ in expansion of $(p_j x + (1-p_j))^m$) for all valid $i$ and $j$.

I don't know if this reduces further, do let me know if anyone knows how to reduce this.
Special cases
The above equation doesn't reduce nicely for small $n$ (uniform or not). Only cases where we get nice closed form formulas are for small $m$:

$E(S_1) = 0$
$E(S_2) = 1 - \sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j^2$
$E(S_3) = \log_2 3 - 2 \sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j^2(1-p_j) - \log_2{3} \sum_{j=1}^{n} p_j^3 $

